# Is this (router) firmware file encrypted?

Tags: decryption, firmware-analysis

I am new to reverse engineering. Nice community you folks have here.

I am trying to determine if this, `VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi` (https://vfcc.publicacs.vodafone.co.uk/firmware/UK-CC/VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi), file is encrypted.

When I attempt to use `binwalk` I get the following:

```sh
$ wget https://vfcc.publicacs.vodafone.co.uk/firmware/UK-CC/VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi
$ binwalk --verbose --term --opcodes VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi

Scan Time:     2024-02-14 17:45:23
Target File:   /home/mbana/dev/router/technicolor-DGA4231VDF-VCNT-I/vbnt-j_vox3uk_19.4.551_1_20210906/release/fwtool/pkg/src/firmware/VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi
MD5 Checksum:  69723e66146a918ac33673c5831ab6b1
Signatures:    34

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6989011       0x6AA4D3        ARMEB instructions, function prologue
9709704       0x942888        ARMEB instructions, function prologue
19163520      0x1246980       ARM instructions, function prologue
26849252      0x199AFE4       ARMEB instructions, function prologue

$ binwalk --verbose --term VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi

Scan Time:     2024-02-14 17:45:31
Target File:   /home/mbana/dev/router/technicolor-DGA4231VDF-VCNT-I/vbnt-j_vox3uk_19.4.551_1_20210906/release/fwtool/pkg/src/firmware/VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi
MD5 Checksum:  69723e66146a918ac33673c5831ab6b1
Signatures:    411

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ binwalk --entropy VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     ENTROPY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Rising entropy edge (0.998205)
$ binwalk --invalid --verbose VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi 

Scan Time:     2024-02-14 17:58:11
Target File:   /home/mbana/dev/router/technicolor-DGA4231VDF-VCNT-I/vbnt-j_vox3uk_19.4.551_1_20210906/release/fwtool/pkg/src/firmware/VOX3v_CLOSED_19.2.0203.3261005.rbi
MD5 Checksum:  69723e66146a918ac33673c5831ab6b1
Signatures:    411

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4317          0x10DD          Private key in DER format (PKCS header length: 4, sequence length: 3904
4317          0x10DD          Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 3904
4317          0x10DD          Object signature in DER format (PKCS header length: 4, sequence length: 3904
8047          0x1F6F          Microsoft executable,
13743         0x35AF          Linux EXT filesystem, blocks count: 454777832, image size: 465692499968, invalid state invalid error behavior invalid major revision rev 838000596.12786, ext3 filesystem data, UUID=1aaf7143-fd18-7bb1-e3db-55c53b373b37, volume name "(V"
```

Some interesting links that might be useful:

- https://lxr.openwrt.org/source/fwtool/
- https://lxr.openwrt.org/source/fwtool/fwtool.c
- https://lxr.openwrt.org/source/fwtool/fwimage.h
- https://lxr.openwrt.org/source/fwtool/crc32.h

I know the router is running OpenWrt and *possibly* using the `fwtool` above to extract the firmware because someone has taken a dump of the rootfs of the router and shared it on GitHub. When I examine `/etc/os-release` I see:

```sh
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="OpenWrt"
VERSION="SNAPSHOT"
ID="openwrt"
ID_LIKE="lede openwrt"
PRETTY_NAME="OpenWrt SNAPSHOT"
VERSION_ID="snapshot"
HOME_URL="http://openwrt.org/"
BUG_URL="http://bugs.openwrt.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forum.lede-project.org/"
BUILD_ID="r10770-7c9a29d500"
LEDE_BOARD="brcm6xxx-tch/VBNTJ"
LEDE_ARCH="arm_cortex-a9"
LEDE_TAINTS="no-all glibc busybox"
LEDE_DEVICE_MANUFACTURER="OpenWrt"
LEDE_DEVICE_MANUFACTURER_URL="http://openwrt.org/"
LEDE_DEVICE_PRODUCT="Generic"
LEDE_DEVICE_REVISION="v0"
LEDE_RELEASE="OpenWrt SNAPSHOT r10770-7c9a29d500"
```

I would appreciate any hints on how to extract or decrypt the firmware file I linked to.

The firmware is a for a router that I have and I want to extend the functionality of the router, basically. I do not intend to do anything illegal.